# C# - Share single declared namespaces from base class/across namespace

Tags: c#, inheritance, namespaces

I tried to google my solution, but I didn't really know how to search it.

I have a base class inside a custom namespace where I want to include a namespace, for example:

```
namespace CustomNameSpace
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class MyBaseClass
    {
        protected List<string> list = new List<string>(); 
    }
}
```

As you can see, my base class uses Generics. Now I'd like to inherit from the base class from another file, also use generics, but not write using `System.Collections.Generic` everytime. for example:

```
namespace CustomNameSpace
{
    public class MyOtherClass : MyBaseClass
    {
        public void CreateNewList()
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

But as we all know, this will give us a resolve issue because the Generic namespace is missing from `MyOtherClass`.

Now, is there a way to 'inherit' `System.Collections.Generic` to all subclasses, or even better, share `System.Collections.Generic` across my whole `CustomNameSpace` namespace?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: You can't. It you want, you can write them in single `.cs` file, but it's not recommended practice. I think you need some tools to automatically find and write namespaces for you like Resharper (https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). It really helps.

Comment: your problem is not about inherit. namespace and inherit concepts are different.

Comment: Yea, single .cs feels like hoarding. I use resharper at work, but at home I develop on a mac, which (as far as I know) doesn't support Visual Studio and resharper :(

Comment: What's the problem with `using %namespace%` within derived type's declaration? Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: If I want to create a lot of Model classes, which will be used to generate UI Elements, it's obvious those things share common namespaces, so why should we declare them in each file? Or am I wrong?

Comment: `using` declarations are entirely a compile-time concept. Once `MyBaseClass` is compiled, it has no concept of which `using` declarations were in scope at the time it was compiled. As such, when `MyOtherClass` is being compiled, it has no access to such information about its base classes nor interfaces.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, that makes sense

Comment: @NickPeelman: maybe, you should consider code generation, if you have many similar classes.